# MySQL SUM() with COUNT() on Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, join, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm pretty new to MySQL, still trying to learn the ropes. Forgive me if this is too basic

I have 3 tables:

Student:

```
Student id|Student name| Gender|Parent id
```

Parent:

```
Parent id|Parent name|Parent Address|Parent Phone|
```

and Classes:

```
Class id|Class Name|Class day
```

and Student Roll call:

```
Student id|Class Id
```

I am trying to perform a count of the number of Student each parent has in the school and the number of Classes each student has.

So far I managed to alter the query to compute the parent name and the number of activities they need to pay for:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',P.Parent_title,P.Parent_fname,P.Parent_sname) AS 'Parent name',
COUNT(RC.Student_id) AS 'Number of Activities'
FROM Student S,Parent P,RollCall RC,Class C
WHERE S.Parent_id=P.Parent_id AND S.Student_id=RC.Student_id AND RC.Class_id=C.Class_id
GROUP BY S.Parent_id;
```

But I'm not sure how to include the `SUM()` to calculate the total amount each parent needs to pay, say if each class is $25.
My professor hinted that I need to use the `CAST()` function, but I'm not sure what I should be using it on. Should I use it on the value of the `COUNT()`?

Thanks again everyone, you have been a huge help. ( I'll also keep working on it).

Comment: Suppose a parent has three children in the school; what will a record in your resultset look like?

Comment: For a parent with 3 children I get:
Parent Name |No. of Students
Mr. John Lot|4

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I meant, if you think about what you're asking, it's really not clear how to join the data together for a parent who has three children in the school.  Your desired results are either only going to show each parent once, in which case what should it show for student name & number of classes? Or else the same parent will appear three times, once for each of their children.  You need to be more clear about how you want the results to look.

Comment: What I would like the results to display Parent name and amount payable. It’s not imperative to see the number of children each parent has or the number of classes each student takes, it just helps me to see if the calculation is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to your comments above, I think this should give you what you're after (total number of enrolled children/classes per parent):

```
SELECT
  CONCAT_WS(' ', Parent_title, Parent_fname, Parent_sname) AS 'Parent name',
  COUNT(DISTINCT Student_id) AS 'Number of students',
  COUNT(DISTINCT Student_id, Class_id) AS 'Number of classes'
FROM
       Parent
  JOIN Student  USING (Parent_id)
  JOIN RollCall USING (Student_id)
  JOIN Class    USING (Class_id)
GROUP BY Parent_id;
```

Comment: @user1361276: Did it do what you wanted?  FYI, you should [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if they work for you (it's why we do it!).  Better yet, if the answer has been helpful to you, you might consider [upvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) it too.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase what you are trying to find, it seems that for each parent, you want to know how many students he has in the school, and how many classes those students have, in aggregate.  I recommend using JOIN syntax to join the 3 tables needed.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',P.Parent_title,P.Parent_fname,P.Parent_sname) AS 'Parent name',
    count(distinct s.student_id) as num_students,
    count(*) as studentclasses 
FROM Parent p
    JOIN Student S
    ON S.parent_id = p.parent_id
        JOIN studentrollcall src
        on s.student_id = src.student_id
GROUP BY 'Parent name'
```

Comment: @user1361276 what error do you get?  The idea behind this join is that the join from parent to student can be one to many, and the join from student to class can be one to many. Therefore, grouping by parent and counting the total number of rows in the resulting join should tell you how many classes are being taken.